# Почему не срабатывает 'анимация' при выставлении height 100%

Tags: css

Есть блок

```
.block-add-feed {
  height: 65px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

И изменение его высоты при наведении

```
.block-add-feed:hover {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Если в hove я укажу, например 175px, то блок плавно увеличивает высоту

А если укажу, например 100%, то блок увеличивает высоту, без анимации, резко

Как это исправить? Сделать плавное увеличение при 100%

Пример рабочего кода:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.block-add-feed {
  height: 65px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.block-add-feed:hover {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="block-add-feed">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @НикитаФаст на сайте стоит в body, height установлен на 100% - не работает, указал в примере( в вопросе) для body и html - height 100%, тоже не работает

Comment: @НикитаФаст можешь написать свое решение в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас допущена ошибка в css

Надо писать через запятую и тогда заработает

для html,body укажите высоту в 100% и потом ваши дочерние блоки увидят высоту в %